# PDO Query with in clause that contain an Array won't work

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I have this code:

```
$Array=array();
array_push($Array,"Email1","Email2");
$Array=implode("','",$Array);
$Array="'$Array'";
echo "$Array" //Will output 'Email1','Email2'
$Check=$connection->prepare("SELECT ID FROM USERS WHERE EMAIL IN(:Array)");
$Check->execute(array(
    ':Array' => $Array,
));
```

This query won't work but if I write:

```
$Check=$connection->prepare("SELECT ID FROM USERS WHERE EMAIL IN('Email1','Email2')");
$Check->execute(array(
    ':Array' => $Array,
));
```

This works, but I won't bind the array to avoid SQL Injection.
How can I fix it?

Comment: comma seperated values isn't good design. consider normalizing your database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to bind the imploded list as one element but rather each of the values individually using `?` so the end of the statement would be `WHERE EMAIL IN (?,?)`:

```
$values  = ["Email1","Email2"];
# This should give you ?,?
$bindstr = implode(",",array_fill(0,count($values),'?'));
$query = $connection->prepare("SELECT ID FROM USERS WHERE EMAIL IN({$bindstr})");
# Use the raw values individually in the execute
$query->execute($values);
```

Hopefully that should get results back you are looking for.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, could you please exaplain me why in the first row you used the [...],and why did you add in the IN CLAUSE the {..}.Anyway thanks for your help, hope that you'll have a nice day:)

Comment: Oh, sorry, the `[` and `]` in newer versions of php is same as using `array()` so `[` = `array(` and `]` = `)`.

Comment: Thanks for have clarified :)

Comment: The `{}` inside the string sort of enforces that you are using a variable inside those braces. I could have not used the braces, but it's better to use them. It's for complex strings: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex

Comment: I can't understand a thing how did you bind the values?Is this query 100% secure against sql injection?Thanks for read, and sorry for another nuisance.

Comment: You bind the the values by putting placeholders using question marks (`?`) for where the values would normally be in the statement, then you put the raw array into the `execute()`.

Comment: So you could have done `WHERE IN (:email1, :email2)` but then you would have to  have used the array `$values = [':email1' => 'Email1',':email2'=>'Email2']; $query->execute($values)`. It's just easier to bind question marks as placeholders rather than an associative array.

Comment: okok understand thanks again for help!